# python: split and create json data from csv

Tags: python, json

How do I create a nested field from csv to json? I looked at the other stackoverflow, but they are not quite what I am trying to format. I have a data set with 1 column that I have to convert into a nested field.

Data:

```
ID, NAME
1, "Smith, Mr. Adams"
2, "McAdams, Mrs. Audrey"
3, "McAdams, Doctor John"
4, "Missing Value"
```

CODE:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
            headers = next(file) #skip the headers
            fieldnames = headers.rstrip().split(",")
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames) #creating a dictionary
            import datetime
            for row_dict in csv_reader:
                row_dict['name'] = row_dict['name'].split(",")
                json_data = json.dumps(row_dict)
                print(json_data)
```

I am getting output in a list but it is not nested.

```
{"id": "1", "name": ["Smith", " Mr. Adams"]}
{"id": "2", "name": ["McAdams", " Mrs. Audrey"]}
{"id": "3", "name": ["McAdams", " Doctor John"]}
{"id": "4", "name": ["Missing Value"]}
```

Final output: Is there any way to do this?

```
{"id": "1", "name": [{"last_name": "Smith",
                      "prefix": "Mr.",
                      "first_name":  "Adams"}]}
{"id": "1", "name": [{"last_name": "McAdams",
                      "prefix": "Mrs.",
                      "first_name":  "Audrey"}]}
{"id": "1", "name": [{"last_name": "McAdams",
                      "prefix": "Dr.",
                      "first_name":  "John"}]}
{"id": "1", "name": [{"last_name": "Missing Value",
                      "prefix": "Missing Value",
                      "first_name":  "Missing Value"}]}
```

Comment: Why is the `name` entry in your desired result a list of a dictionary instead of just a dictionary?

Comment: You need to write a function that parses the name into the dictionary you want. You can't just use `split()`, because that won't extract the prefix, and won't put `Missing Value` into all the missing fields.

Comment: Names have many different formats, so this is likely to be complicated and produce errors for cases you don't handle properly. This is why forms usually have separate input fields for first name, last name, title, etc.

Comment: For the final output, check this out https://github.com/datamade/probablepeople. I am using it at the moment, not perfect but certainly beats implementing it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.split()` some times and create a new dict.

```
import json

csv = '''1, "Smith, Mr. Adams"
2, "McAdams, Mrs. Audrey"
3, "McAdams, Doctor John"
4, "Missing Value"'''

csv_lines = csv.split('\n')


for line in csv_lines:
  id = line.split(',')[0]
  name = line[len(id)+3:-1]
  split = name.split(', ')
  last_name = split[0]
  if len(split) < 2:
    first_name = last_name
    prefix = last_name
  else:
    prefix = split[1].split(' ')[0]
    first_name = split[1][len(prefix)+1:]

  row_dict = {'id': id, 'name': {'last_name': last_name, 'prefix': prefix, 'first_name': first_name}}

  json_data = json.dumps(row_dict)
  print(json_data)
```

Output:

```
{"id": "1", "name": {"last_name": "Smith", "prefix": "Mr.", "first_name": "Adams"}}
{"id": "2", "name": {"last_name": "McAdams", "prefix": "Mrs.", "first_name": "Audrey"}}
{"id": "3", "name": {"last_name": "McAdams", "prefix": "Doctor", "first_name": "John"}}
{"id": "4", "name": {"last_name": "Missing Value", "prefix": "Missing Value", "first_name": "Missing Value"}}
```

Comment: If the name dict really has to be in a list, you easy could implement this by changing the line where the row_dict is created.